# How to export Speak to wav or mp3 file?

Tags: export, sound

How to export `Speak["valentine"]` to wav or mp3 file?

Comment: You might want `SpeechSynthesize` instead. `Export["valentine.wav", SpeechSynthesize["valentine"]]` works fine.

Comment: Thank You! Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

[`Speak`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Speak.html) does not generate an output object (it returns `Null`). It only has the side effect of producing the synthesized sounds, so it is not straightforward to export the generated audio directly.

On the other hand, [`SpeechSynthesize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpeechSynthesize.html) returns an [`Audio`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Audio.html) object, which here appears to behave essentially as a wrapper for a .WAV file automatically generated somewhere on your computer.

As [Carl Lange mentioned in his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236078/how-to-export-speak-to-wav-or-mp3-file#comment596211_236078), this object can be exported directly using `Export`:

```
Export["valentine.wav", SpeechSynthesize["valentine"]
```